# Reuse same view and logic just change the endpoints in VUE

Tags: javascript, vue.js, code-reuse

I came to an point where i have a bunch of endpoints that behave the same like:

> http:://api.development/projects/status/types
>
> http:://api.development/projects/errors/types
>
> http:://api.development/projects/priority/types

They all have the same verbs: GET, POST (add), PUT (edit) and DELETE and they share the same data structure:

```
{
    name: "",
    description: ""
}
```

Therefore the view and the logic to manage that on my client will be the same.

I am using VUE for the client. I thought of creating a component to reuse the view and create three other components that includes that component. Therefore the logic will be written in all of this three parent components.

But how can I implement the logic to reuse it across them? The only piece of code will change will be the endpoints.

Comment: How do you plan to implement the logic if there is only 1 component, and what obstacles do you expect to come into if you want to reuse the logic by passing props? Not sure what your actual difficulty is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a service file, and there you declare your API calls, and then just export that file as a component and reuse the calls anywhere in your app.

It would look something like this:

```js
import axios from 'axios'
const api = 'API'

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      user: `${api}/some/route`,
      hotels: `${api}/other/route/`
    }
  },
  methods: {
    getHeaders() {
      return {
        headers: {
          Authorization: 'Bearer ' + 'TOKEN',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
      }
    },
    getModule(route, cb) {
      axios
        .get(route, this.getHeaders())
        .then(response => {
          cb(response.data)
        })
        .catch(err => {
          cb(err)
        })
    },
    postModule(route, data, cb) {
      axios
        .post(route, data, this.getHeaders())
        .then(response => {
          cb(response.data)
        })
        .catch(e => {
          cb(e)
        })
    },
    putModule(route, data, cb) {
      axios
        .put(route, data, this.getHeaders())
        .then(response => {
          cb(response.data)
        })
        .catch(e => {
          console.log(e)
        })
    },
    deleteModule(route, id, cb) {
      axios
        .delete(route + id, this.getHeaders())
        .then(response => {
          cb(response.data)
        })
        .catch(e => {
          console.log(e)
        })
    }
  }
}
```

In the component where you want to execute the call you do this:

```js
import ServiceFileName from '@/services/YourServiceFileName'

methods:{
getData () {
      Main.methods.getModule(Main.data().hotels, data => {
        console.log(data)
      })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You mean something like [mixins](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html)?